# Different Feature Importance in Naive Bayes

Tags: python, pandas, naivebayes

I want to know the top 20 important features in Naive Bayes. I have two classes in target feature. By exploring other forms in stackoverflow I found the reference code for my code. 
Code:

```
neg_class_prob_sorted = multi_nb_best_alpha_bow.feature_log_prob_[0, :].argsort()
pos_class_prob_sorted = multi_nb_best_alpha_bow.feature_log_prob_[1, :].argsort()

print(np.take(multi_nb_best_alpha_bow_vec.get_feature_names(), neg_class_prob_sorted[-20:]))
print(np.take(multi_nb_best_alpha_bow_vec.get_feature_names(), pos_class_prob_sorted[-20:]))
```

Can someone provide me the intuition on why the probability importance different for each class ?
If we need to select the top 20 or so features to apply predict on test set ?
Thanks for your help